# Angular ng-if not rendering div upon condition change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-geolocation, angularjs-ng-if

I'm working on learning Angular with Google maps and having difficulty rendering a map within a div controlled by an ng-if directive.

For my application, I would like the map render upon receiving the coordinates from the $scope.location function. I would then click on a button and invoke $scope.myRide in order to place a marker on the map. However, what is happening is that the map does not render until I click on the button.
The coordinates within $scope.map are serve as placeholders until the actual coordinates are received from $scope.location.
Any assistance will be greatly appreciated :)

```
angular.module('MapView',[])
.config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
    // the state will go on the html that you want route the user.
    .state('mapView', {
        url: '/mapView',
        templateUrl: 'app/mapView/mapView.html',
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 38, longitude: -122 }, zoom: 15 };
            $scope.output = document.getElementById("loc");
            $scope.maker = {};

            $scope.coords = {};

            $scope.mockUsers = [{username: 'young', mess: 'I need a ride at 9am'},{username: 'young', mess: 'I need a ride at 9am'}, {username: 'young', mess: 'I need a ride at 9am'}]

            $scope.location = function(){
                if (!navigator.geolocation){
                  output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
                  return;
                }
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                  console.log('current position',position.coords)
                   $scope.map.center.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                   $scope.coords.lat = position.coords.latitude; //added this
                   $scope.map.center.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                   $scope.coords.lon = true; // added this
                }, function(){
                  $scope.output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
                });
            }()


             $scope.myRide = function(){
                $scope.maker.latitude = $scope.map.center.latitude;
                $scope.maker.longitude = $scope.map.center.longitude;
             }
        },
        controllerAs: 'LoginCtrl'
    });
})
```

The following is the HTML:

```
<div ui-sref='mapView' >

  <div ng-show = "coords.lon == true">Hello</div>

    <div id="loc"></div>


    <div id="mapDiv" ng-if="coords.lon">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' maker=>
            <ui-gmap-marker  coords="maker" icon="icon" idkey="1"></ui-gmap-marker> 
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-Center">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click='myRide()' >Ride</button>
    </div>

    <div id="mapUsers">
        <div class="clear" ng-repeat='user in mockUsers'>
            <div class="mapUserImg">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://falconbus.in/images/site/user_icon.png">
            </div>
            <h1> {{ user.username }} </h1>
            <p> {{ user.mess}} </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: try to change ng-if by ng-show, ng-if open a new scope, so is possible you lost your binding for that ng-show use the same scope.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, ng-show makes the situation even worse. The map still does not render automatically - and clicking on a button opens the map window but it's blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some recomendations,

1) for debugging you can install the chrome extension [ng-inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj)  in there you can view what value you have in center and zoom when you are in the html side, check if the data have sense.

2) i thing you use angular-google-maps from [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/marker)  if is true, you have two errors,

```
    <div id="mapDiv" ng-if="coords.lon">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' **maker=**>
        <ui-gmap-marker  coords="maker" **icon="icon"** idkey="1"></ui-gmap-marker> 
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

marker empty is not necesesary and icon do are inside to options like the example in the official website.

```
<div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
    <ui-gmap-marker coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
    </ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
<div ng-cloak>
    <ul>
        <li>coords update ctr: {{coordsUpdates}}</li>
        <li>dynamic move ctr: {{dynamicMoveCtr}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

3) in the [anglar-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/marker) website you can use Edit in Plnkr for made some first test to familiarize with this directives

Answer (score 0):

```
[<script src="~/Scripts/app/Home.js"></script>  
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-md-12">  
            <h1>AngularJS Examples</h1>  
            <div ng-app="myApp" style="width:400px;">  
                <div ng-controller="homeController">  
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
                        <tbody>  
                            <tr>  
                                <td>Person Name:</td>  
                                <td>  
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="Person.personName" />  
                                </td>  
                            </tr>  
                            <tr>  
                                <td>Person Age:</td>  
                                <td>  
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="Person.personAge" />  
                                </td>  
                            </tr>  
                            <tr>  
                                <td colspan="2" align="center">  
                                    <div class="alert alert-info" ng-if="Person.personAge < 18">  
                                        Person Age must be <strong>above 18 years.</strong>  
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" ng-if="Person.personAge >= 18 && Person.personAge <= 100">  
                                        <strong>Valid Age.</strong>  
                                    </div>  
                                    <div ng-if="Person.personAge > 100" class="alert alert-warning">  
                                        Person Age must be <strong> between 18 and 100.</strong>  
                                    </div>  
                                </td>  
                            </tr>  
                        </tbody>  
                    </table>  
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

[learn from c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/17e8f6/difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-in-angularjs/)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that upon receiving the coordinates, If I click anywhere on the page the map will load. I thus modified the js file to simulate a click, and it works. Although this works for my application, I'm still not sure what the root issue of the problem is. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the function I modified by adding a .click() :

```
$scope.location = function(){
                if (!navigator.geolocation){
                  output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
                  return;
                }
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                  console.log('current position',position.coords)
                   $scope.map.center.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                   $scope.coords.lat = position.coords.latitude; //added this
                   $scope.map.center.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                   $scope.coords = true; // added this
                   document.getElementById('loc').click();
                }, function(){
                  $scope.output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
                });
            }()
```